# can someone please tell why " -'0' "is being done in the fifth line of following function

Tags: c

```
 m=1e9 + 7;
inline ll rem(char s[],ll m)
{
     ll sum=0 , i;
     for(i=0;S[i]!='\0';i++)
     {
          if(sum>=m)
            sum %= m;
          sum=(sum * 10 + S[i] - '0');
     }
     return sum%m;
}
```

here `S[i]` is a string of integer characters. My question is
what does `-'0'` does here, also can a character (here `S[i]`) be automatically converted to integer form is the above

```
sum=(sum * 10 + S[i] - '0');
```

equation.

Comment: to convert ascii digits to integer values

Comment: Subtracting `'0'` from a character will give you its numeric value, assuming the character was representing a numeral.

Comment: Someone please find a duplicate for this, it can't be the first time someone has asked.

Comment: Not even the second or third, I'm sure.

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to remember that characters in C are represented as tiny integers corresponding to the character's value in the machine's character set, which is typically ASCII.

For example, `'A'` n ASCII is 65, and `'0'` is 48.

So if you're converting a string of digits to an integer, you want to do something like

```
int digit = c - 48;
```

That converts `'0'` to 0, `'1'` to 1, etc.

But that magic number 48 is mystifying, and it's theoretically also wrong on a machine using a character set other than ASCII.  So the easier (because you don't have to remember that value 48), self-documenting (as long as your reader understands the idiom), and more portable way is to do

```
int digit = c - '0';
```

This works because, as I said, `'0'` is 48 in ASCII.  But, more importantly, even on a non-ASCII machine, `'0'` is whatever value the character `'0'` has in that machine's character set, so it's always the right value to subtract, no matter what kind of machine you're using.

Comment: And C requires `'0' .. '9'` to be represented contiguously.